# Orientdb use @rid in another property like slug

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientjs

I am trying to create a slug(prettyurl) for each post added by the user. And use this slug to access the record in the db. The generated slugs might not be unique so I thought of adding the @rid at the end of the slug. So that the slugs will be unique and I can retrieve the record with the @rid while fetching the record. I can use this slug in the restful url's as well(after removing the # in the @rid).

So is there a way to append the rid to the slug property while inserting the record?

Or is there  an auto increment field in orientdb which I can concatenate with the slug?

Or is there any other way to achieve the same result? I thought about generating a unique id from node js but this might add the overhead of creating and managing unique filed across multiple servers.

I am using

orientjs version: 2.1.0

orientdb version 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

Slug thing what you have explained I can not understand.
However `@rid` that is the Record Identifier in OrientDB is unique and it resembles like `Primary Key` of our Relational Database System.

to `append` the `@rid` you can use `slug.append(@rid)` but at the time of `INSERT`, it may not work as `@rid` is determined after the `INSERT`.

You can use `INSERT.. RETURN @rid` read it from [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Insert.html)

However, for the Auto Increment purpose, I would say that `@rid` is automatically incremented. It is decided as `#clusterIDOfTheRecord:positionOfTheRecordInTheCluster`.

So, `autoincrement` there may not be needed.